# how to solve error converting yaml to Json?

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, yaml, kubectl, app.yaml

it's my code there is an error in it?

```
apiVersion: V1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-dypl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
   matchLabels:
    app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: platformservice
   spec:
    containers:
      - name: platformservice
        image: mohamedfouadmohamed/platformservice
```

Comment: where is the error? how you are trying to convert? please add enough details https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have a bad indentation before the second `spec` (line 15).
This works fine:

```yaml
apiVersion: V1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-dypl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
   matchLabels:
    app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
       app: platformservice
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: platformservice
        image: mohamedfouadmohamed/platformservice
```

You can use a python linter for your yaml project to avoid this syntax problem, for example [yamllint](https://pypi.org/project/yamllint/).

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors :

- apiVersion of deployment
- indentation of `spec:`

Correct yaml file should be :

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # it should be apps/v1 not V1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: platforms-dypl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
   matchLabels:
    app: platformservice
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: platformservice
    spec: # corrected indentation
      containers:
      - name: platformservice
        image: mohamedfouadmohamed/platformservice
```